# How do I install Brother HL-2280dw network printer?

Tags: printing, brother

New to Ubuntu (using 15.04) and trying to install a couple of Network printers I have. Brother HL-2280dw, and Brother MFC-J870dw. I downloaded the Linux deb drivers from Brother's support site and the application installer will give a message to not install.

Why?

Also tried directly by connecting to the network printer, and letting Ubuntu look for drivers and install from a free site it recommended, but during the installation it froze, and I had to reboot.

Answer (score 6):

My Brother HL2280DW is pinned on the network.  My new new 16.04 Ubuntu instance was configured by:

Start Gear (upper right corner) => System settings => Printer => Add button

The 2280 was **not** an option, so I recommend downloading and installing the driver per the OEM.
Driver install instructions:

http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadhowto.aspx?c=us_ot&lang=en&prod=hl2280dw_us&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625

Invoke the installation script: not the model number is appended as an argument.

```
sudo bash linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.1-1 HL-2280D
```

When faced with selecting the connection type and its configuration:  the printer is network (LAN) configured so I selected the IP address option.

> Will you specify the Device URI? [Y/n] ->Y

Select option 11 => specify IP address

Type in the address and script will prompt to print test page

Ring the bell and increment the counter if you were successful with setting up your printer.